# Is anyone else experiencing this issue when installing Docker Desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, installation, docker-desktop

I'm attempting to install *Docker Desktop* on my *Windows 10 Pro 21H2 system*, but getting the following error:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: Not found 
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

- C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop contains an *install-log-admin.txt*, I'll provide the output [here](https://pastebin.com/DXnXkiE9)

Comment: Google finds several discussions and possible solutions to the error when searching for the first two lines.

Comment: @JasonHarrison, I appreciate your response, but I've tried many of the results Google returns.